# UK visitor visa without any property

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

Required documents for UK visitor visa applicants are:

1. Bank Statements
2. Property Papers
3. Employer letter, payslips, etc.
4. Sponsor's details (letter, statements, passport copy)

If someone has all possible documents, except for no property in her/his name, is it possible to make a credible application?  Is there a realistic chance of success?

Comment: If you do not own any property, then the bank statements and payslips will have to look better than they would if you owned real estate. A good and steady salary will be the **main** factor.

Comment: @dan1111, yes you have improved the question, thanks for your help, it's no longer an opinion poll per se... Hopefully now you can provide the OP with a bell-ringer answer.

Comment: Not everyone who gets a UK Visa owns any estate...

Comment: Which country are you a citizen of (and are resident in, if different)? The UK's visa policy is different for different origin countries.

Comment: CSM I am from Pakistan and living in Islamabad Capital of Pakistan

Answer (score 4):

Those don't seem to be **required** documents. Since you're asking for a visitor visa, according to their guidance: [Visitor: supporting documents guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf), the only required document is your passport and photo. For the supporting documents ("other documents you may want to provide"), it lists the following:

> - Previous travel documents/passports, which show previous travel.
> - Financial documents showing that you have sufficient funds available.
>     These must  clearly show that you have access to the funds, such as:
>     bank statements, building society book, proof of earnings such as a
>     letter from employer confirming employment details (start date of
>     employment, salary, role, company contact details)
> - where a third
>     party (who is either in the UK or who will be legally in the UK at 
>     the time of your visit ) is providing financial support to you e.g. a
>     business, a  friend or a relative, documents to show they have
>     sufficient resources to support you in addition to themselves and any
>     dependant family should be provided
> - Confirmation of legal residence, if you are not a national of the
>     country in which you are applying or your right to reside there is not
>     included in your passport.
> - Details of employment or studies where you
>     have stated in your application that you are either employed or in
>     full-time studies. This could include:  a letter from your employer on
>     company headed paper, detailing your role,  salary and length of
>     employment, a letter from your education provider,  on headed paper,
>     confirming your enrolment and leave of absence.
> - If self employed:
>     business  registration documents confirming the business owner’s  name
>     and the date the business started trading

Please note that this list doesn't even mention deeds or other evidence of property ownership!

Now, from personal experience: I know several Russians who got UK visitor visas while owning no real property. All however were employed with good income, traveled to other countries before, and were in their 30s.

Comment: MR George Y Thank you for your answer What do you mean by "Building Society Book" ?? You mean property documents?

Comment: "Building society" is like a community-owned bank; by depositing your money there you technically own a share of a bank. This is UK-specific term; here in US the closest would be "credit union". This is NOT real property.

Comment: You're welcome. If you accept the answer, so it wouldn't show up in "Unanswered", this would be appreciated!